# Unable to insert date in Masked TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

I have a masked textbox in my winforms application. I pull out date from database which comes as `2/9/2012` and try to insert the same in masked textbox but the textbox displays it as `29/20/12__`.

Please find the final piece of code which I tried.

```
if (value.HasValue)
{
    txtDate.AppendText("    ");
    string month = value.Value.Month.ToString();
    bool insertMonthZero = false;
    if (month.Length == 1)
    {
        //month = "0" + month;
        txtDate.Text = '0' + month;
        insertMonthZero = true;
    }
    else
    {
        txtDate.Text = month;
    }
    string day = value.Value.Day.ToString();
    bool insertDayZero = false;
    if (day.Length == 1)
    {
        insertDayZero = true;
    }
    else
    {
        txtDate.AppendText(day);
    }
    string year = value.Value.Year.ToString();
    txtDate.Text = value.Value.Date.ToShortDateString(); //txtDate.Text + year;
    if (insertMonthZero)
    {
        txtDate.Text.Insert(0, "0");
    }
    if (insertDayZero)
    {
        txtDate.Text.Insert(2, "0");
    }
    //txtDate.AppendText(year);
    // txtDate.Text = "0" + month + "/" + day + "/" + value.Value.Year.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What mask is on the textbox, and what type of `value`? Is it `DateTime?` as I suppose?

Comment: It looks like what you're looking for can be handled with a custom ToString format: value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Comment: @Andy yes value is of type DateTime?

Comment: @Zeph I tried .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") but got no success.

Comment: @Sunny But what about mask? what exactly it is?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I masked the TextBox with the predefined ShortDate type

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Its the MaskedTextBox which comes along WinForms and we have some predefined types such as Date type which I used

Comment: @Sunny so why don't you just simply use something like `txtDate.Text = value.ToShortDateString()` instead of all code you've written?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I even tried that but the Zeros are still getting suppressed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is caused by a date formatting issue.  You are getting 2/9/2012 from you database but your textbox mask is expecting a date in the format mm/dd/yyyy.  Try formatting the database returned date into that format before setting the textbox's value.

Comment: I treid but the issue is with the MaskedTextBox it is suppressing the leading zeros.

Comment: What is the mask property set to on your MaskedTextbox?

Comment: This link may help you with what you are experiencing.  The user VadimKa gives a solution that looks to have helped resolve the issue.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windows.developer.mediacenter/-6v02nx-ZsU

Comment: I used ShortDate as the mask property

Comment: No that won't work for me as I don't have bindings everything is assigned on runtime.